# Deploy MVC 3 and MVC 5 website on same server IIS 7

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, web-deployment

I've a mvc 3 application running on IIS 7. Now I've upgraded it to MVC 5. Is it possible to to deploy both applications i.e MVC 3 and MVC 5 on the same server using IIS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can host both MVC 3 to MVC 5 application on IIS 7 with no issue.
But if you say you had upgraded it to MVC 5 then why you want MVC 3 version of that application.

Could you please provide more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually our MVC 3 application is in UAT so we need it deployed too.

Comment: And our future releases will be in MVC 5. Is there any restrictions in doing so like dlls and all that?

Comment: Nope. All the MVC related DLLs are in the BIN folder and not in the GAC. So your application will pickup appropriate MVC version

Answer (score 0):

I only installed MVC 5 on server and it worked properly. No extra effort required.